# react-native iOS CFBundleIdentifier

Tags: ios, react-native

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/foodApp.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/foodApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist.

I've been trying to fix this issue. I have tried many solutions that were suggested but I still get this.

Comment: Please check your app Info.plist has CFBundleIdentifier? For the iOS app, this is a mandatory field in Info.plist.

Comment: I just checked the Info.plist file and there is information related to CFBundleIdentifier

Comment: You probably call PlistBuddy util from wrong directory or with wrong argument.

Comment: build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/foodApp.app/Info.plist. For sure, it doesn't have the CFBundleIdentifier. Please check your app has multiple info.plist files and your script is coming the wrong one?